# How to set the resolution on the CentOS 7 login screen?

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, centos-7

I’ve set the screen resolution on my CentOS 7 VM. But although the resolution is correct once I’ve logged in, the login screen resolution is far too high.

I cannot find a way to change it. Does anyone have any ideas? I’m using Gnome.

Comment: I had an opposite-looking problem where everything looks too big in the login screen and it scrolls when you move the mouse to the edges - you can only see part of it at once. Turns out I had the "Zoom" setting on in the accessibility menu (icon with a human in a circle at the top right of the login screen).

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings, and Display. Then select Apply on the right/bottom. Then copy `/home/yourusername/.config/monitors.xml` into `/var/lib/gdm/.config/`